# How to mock Perl module Time::HiRes

Tags: perl, testing, mocking

There is a great Perl module [Time::HiRes](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aHiRes). I heavily use it in my library and want to write some tests. I have found 2 CPAN modules that mocks perl `time()` function, but both of them don't support [Time::HiRes](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aHiRes):

- [Time::Mock](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aMock)
- [Test::MockTime](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aMockTime)

How can I mock [Time::HiRes](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aHiRes) sub `gettimeofday()`?

PS I want to fix tests for my module [Time::ETA](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aETA). Now I use ugly hack with `sleep` "mock", [sometimes it works and sometimes it does not](https://travis-ci.org/bessarabov/Time-ETA/builds/9657336).

Comment: do you want something like `set_fixed_time_of_day` sub?

Comment: I was thinking of what I want. I want to be able to stop time in my test script. After I run `my $ts = CORE::time(); set_fixed_time($ts);` (or something like that) the `time()` and `Time::HiRes::gettimeofday()` will return the same values until I explicitly run `$ts++; set_fixed_time($ts);`

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own module <strike>with blackjack and hookers</strike> to mock gettimeofday. By some modifications of Test::MockTime i wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package myMockTime;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw( import );
use Time::HiRes ();
use Carp;

our @fixed = ();
our $accel = 1;
our $otime = Time::HiRes::gettimeofday;

our @EXPORT_OK = qw(
    set_fixed_time_of_day
    gettimeofday
    restore
    throttle
);

sub gettimeofday() {
    if ( @fixed ) {
        return wantarray ? @fixed : "$fixed[0].$fixed[1]";
    }
    else {
        return $otime + ( ( Time::HiRes::gettimeofday - $otime ) * $accel );
    }
}

sub set_fixed_time_of_day {
    my ( $time1, $time2 ) = @_;
    if ( ! defined $time1 || ! defined $time2 ) {
        croak('Incorrect usage');
    }
    @fixed = ( $time1, $time2 );
}

sub throttle {
    my $self = shift @_;
    return $accel unless @_;
    my $new = shift @_;
    $new or croak('Can not set throttle to zero');
    $accel = $new;
}

sub restore {
    @fixed = ();
}

1;
```

I think it has a lot of bugs and incomplete functionallity, work in this direction

Comment: Yep =) This is a solution. But I hoped that this problem was already solved. And I think it is better not to write a new module, but try to patch Time::Mock or Test::MockTime.

Comment: `use Exporter; *import = \&Exporter::import; import() if 0;` can be written `use Exporter qw( import );`

Comment: thanks, it was copy-paste from original Test::MockTime + hack to disable warning)

Answer (score 1):

Try [`Test::MockTime::HiRes`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::MockTime::HiRes):

> `Test::MockTime::HiRes` is a `Time::HiRes` compatible version of `Test::MockTime`. You can wait milliseconds in simulated time.

There's also [`Test::Mock::Time`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Mock::Time) if you want to mock functions like `clock_nanosleep`